# Select returns empty result when injecting a variable in the query string

Tags: php, python, mysql

I try the following PHP code:

```
$db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root','');

mysql_select_db('mydatabase',$db);
$sql = 'SELECT id from user where name = \''.$my_name.'\'';
//$sql = 'SELECT id from user where name=\'Some Name \'';

echo $sql.'<br>';
$req=  mysql_query($sql) or die('Erreur SQL !<br>'.$sql.'<br>'.mysql_error()); 
$data = mysql_fetch_assoc($req);
mysql_close();
if($data) {
    echo 'id from database= '.$data['id'].'<br>';
    $id = $data['id'];
}
```

But it never enters on the `if($data)` statement.
As you can see I try to print the sql request; and if I copy paste it to the mysql database, it returns the expected ID.

Note that the variable $my_name not empty and has the correct data. More strange, if I uncomment the line:

```
//$sql = 'SELECT id from user where name=\'Some Name \'';
```

it works, and the data in `$my_name` is "Some Name "...

I make other request in my code, all work fine, except this one.

Last Note: the variable is taken from an extern python script:

```
$command = escapeshellcmd('python /var/my_script.py '.$id_for python);
$my_name = shell_exec($command);
echo htmlspecialchars($my_name).'<br>';
```

So it seems to be something wong between data returns from the python script and the use of it in the mysql request...

### EDIT

In Fact it should be an issue with python script. I cannot even insert the data in the database from python:

```
import operator
import sys
import MySQLdb
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup, Comment, BeautifulStoneSoup
bugs = ""
username = "username";
password = "passwd#";
display = Display(visible=0, size = (800, 600))
display.start()
driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('somesite')
driver.find_element_by_name('ctl00$contextHolder$Login_name').send_keys(username)
driver.find_element_by_name('ctl00$contextHolder$Login_password').send_keys(password)
driver.find_element_by_name('ctl00$contextHolder$LoginButton').click()
display = Display(visible=0, size = (800, 600))
display.start()
driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('somesite')
driver.find_element_by_name('ctl00$contextHolder$Login_name').send_keys(username)
driver.find_element_by_name('ctl00$contextHolder$Login_password').send_keys(password)
driver.find_element_by_name('ctl00$contextHolder$LoginButton').click()

try:
    driver.get('https://somesite/SearchTicketPr.aspx')
    driver.find_element_by_name('ctl00$MainContent$SearchTickets$TB_TicketId').send_keys(sys.argv[1])
    driver.find_element_by_name('ctl00$MainContent$SearchTickets$B_Search').click()
    soup = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*").get_attribute("outerHTML")
    reporter = soup.split('ctl00_MainContent_DG_TicketList_ctl03_L_EscalationFlg">')[1].split('</td><td>')[4]

    # We need to insert the reporter and mantis id directly in database
    #For Linux, this is a casual package (python-mysqldb). (You can use sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb in command line to download.)
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", # your host, usually localhost
                     user="root", # your username
                      passwd="", # your password
                      db="myDB") # name of the data base

    # you must create a Cursor object. It will let
    #  you execute all the queries you need
    cur = db.cursor() 
    sql_req= "INSERT INTO ticket (number, username) VALUES ('" + sys.argv[1] + "', '" + reporter + "')"
    print sql_req
    # Use all the SQL you like
    cur.execute(sql_req)

    print reporter
<pre> <code> 
except:
    driver.quit()
    display.stop()
    raise
```

This prints the reported variable correctly, the printed sql request is well printed too. There is no error message, but the data are not inserted in the database.

It maybe something wrong with the encoding?

Comment: print `$my_name` so you're sure its the value you expect.

Comment: I printed it already, it is what I expected; even more, I print the sql request and copy/paste in the mysql CLI: it works. But it doesn't work if I get the result of the python script directly from php code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
...

$sql = "SELECT id from user where name = '".$my_name."'";

...
```

If the first line gives you an error because your `$my_name` var contain an illegal char or something like that, you should verify it before send it with the sql request.

Comment: NO. You're wrong, my first line is well giving SELECT id from user where name = 'my_name'; note the escap character...

Answer (score 0):

That is because your query is wrong, please change this:

```
 $sql = 'SELECT id from user where name = \''.$my_name.'\'';
```

To:

```
 $sql = "SELECT id from user where name = '$my_name'";
```